# Compare all numbers positive and negative in column A and produce a unique random number in cell B5

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a random number that does not match a number in column A which has both positive and negative numbers.

The number produced needs to be positive and returned to cell B5, preferably as a value, from a button.

I used vlookup and rand in Excel but am only getting lists.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you could do this is, in a loop, generate a random number and then check if it's in column A. If it is not in column A, then break the loop and output the number.

```
Function getRandNotInColumnA() as Integer
    Do While True
        rand = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 100)    
        If Not WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("A:A"), rand) > 0 Then 
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop        
    getRandNotInColumnA = rand
End Function
```

That can be used in a VBA subroutine:

```
Sub test()
   Debug.Print (getRandNotInColumnA())
End Sub
```

Or as a UDF inside a cell formula

```
=getRandNotInColumnA()
```